# mini-css-extract-plugin does not load css if it is not declared via dynamic import

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have very basic webpack + mini-css-extract-plugin project (you can found it [here](https://github.com/sprilukin/mini-css-extract-plugin-issue)).

Here is `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // file loader allows to copy file to the build folder and form proper url
            // usually images are used from css files, see css loader below
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: "_assets/[name].[ext]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // css files are processed to copy any dependent resources like images
            // then they copied to the build folder and inserted via link tag
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                sideEffects: true,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // for tests we use simplified raw-loader for css files
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            // public path has changed so url(...) inside css files use relative pathes
                            // like: url(../_assets/image.png) instead of absolute urls
                            publicPath: '../',
                        }
                    },
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // plugin helps to properly process css files which are imported from the source code
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: '_assets/[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '_assets/[id].css'
        })
    ],
    entry: {
        'test': "./src/test"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), `public`),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '_chunks/chunk.[name].js'
    }
};
```

main entry file `test.js`:

```js
import './css/testCss.css';

console.log('Loaded');
```

When i run webpack build i got the following output structure:

```
/
|-test.js
|-_assets/
| |-test.css
```

When i include this js bundle into html i would expect that test.js bundle will load `test.css` file dynamically but this is not the case - js bundle works ok, but css file is not loaded at all.

It is only loaded when i modify source of the `test.js` like so:

```js
import('./css/testCss.css');  // <--------- NOTE: dynamic import here

console.log('Loaded');
```

in this case after webpack build i got the following output:

```
/
|-test.js
|-_assets/
| |-0.css
|-_chunks/
| |-chunk.0.js
```

and when i load this js bundle in html - it loads both `chink.0.js` and `0.css`

**MAIN QUESTION:** Is dynamic import the only correct way to include css into my js files via `mini-css-extract-plugin`?

Because in documentation they say yo use normal static import like `import "./test.css"`

my environement info:

```
node version: v14.12.0
webpack version: 4.44.1 (also tested on 5.2.0)
mini-css-extract-plugin version 1.1.2
```

Comment: Did you ever find out how this works, @SergeyP? I'm having the same problem and can't really figure out what should be the correct way to import the css file. 
At least using the dynamic import really works, thanks for that!

Comment: Maybe using https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin could help